# API для сайта или сайт на API?

Tags: php, api, веб-программирование

Доброго времени препровождения. Сего дня мне задали вопрос, на который я даже и затруднился ответить, "*Что лучше написать API для готового сайта или же проще сконцентрировать свои силы на 'общем API', а уже потом на нем построить сайт и все прилагающиеся приложения?*". Помогите ответить по этому вопросу и дайте расширенный ответ, почему стоит сделать так, а не так.

Comment: Забыл сказать, я за то, что сначала нужно написать сайт, а уже потом думать об API, для него.

Comment: второй вариант вполне хорош. Можно, к примеру, сделать ядро сайта на одном сервере, а web версию - на другом (других). Разделяй и властвуй!

А цеплять апи к готовому серверу имеет один недостаток. Если что то где то поменялось, то придется переделывать сразу две части.

Comment: думаю что второй вариант будет правильней - есть данные, под них делается все остальное, примерно, сначала спроектировать БД, потом уже делать приложение, которое будет ею пользоваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim):*

Второй вариант вполне хорош. Можно, к примеру, сделать ядро сайта на одном сервере, а web версию — на другом (других). Разделяй и властвуй!

А цепляние API к готовому серверу имеет один недостаток. Если что то где то поменялось, то придется переделывать сразу две части.